# Правильно-ли я понял концепцию MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Хотел уточнить своё понимание концепции.
Я понял что работать всё должно примерно так:

url разбирает роутер, определяя какой контроллер будет обрабатывать запрос

Далее подключается нужный контроллер, а если подходящего контроллера не найдено - вид отдаёт 404 ошибку.

Если контроллер успешно подключен, он извлекает необходимые данные через модели, получает некоторый массив необходимых данных и передаёт их в вид

Вид принимает данные и вставляет их в нужные места шаблона и выдает результат

Я правильно понял?

**Второстепенный вопрос:** нормально-ли вызывать другие контроллеры из контроллера?

И ещё один второстепенный вопрос. Можно ли назвать контроллер сценарием страницы? Ведь по сути он манипулирует данными (через модели) и приводит их в необходимый для вьювера вид, например в массив.

То есть всё работает так:

site/news

Роутер: я ищу в папке controllers news.php, если нахожу - произвожу инклуд.

Контроллер news.php: я запрашиваю у моделей (классов) необходимую информацию, например массив из последних 10 новостей, общее их количество, количество страниц с новостями и т.д.

Теперь я передаю данные в вьювер новостей "news.php"

Вьювер news.php: я отвечаю за то, что увидит в итоге пользователь.
В цикле перебирающем пришедшие данные я подключаю шаблон short_article для каждой новости и передаю туда данные о заголовке, тексте, дате и авторе (для примера), а в ответ получаю сгенерированный html код который передаю в конструктор шаблона article_list, в ответ получаю опять же html который передаю в шаблон main вместе с другими данными полученными от  контроллера.

Собранную строку я (функция) возвращаю обратно в контроллер, который в свою очередь выводит её пользователю. Работа скрипта завершена, пользователь видит страницу из шаблона main (основной шаблон сайта), где в $content вставлен шаблон article_list (обертка для списка материалов с навигацией по страницам), где в $content вставлена строка собранная из шаблонов short_article.

Если вдруг какого-то шаблона не обнаруживается, выбрасывается исключение и контроллер может точно доложить о том, что такого-то шаблона не существует (ну или просто ошибку 500 в продакшене).

---

Правильно ли я описал пример работы или нет?

---

И вот ещё. Кто должен выводить данные пользователю? Контроллер или вьювер?

**Вот варианты**:

Контроллер:
Собираю данные.
Передаю в вьювер

Вьювер:
Собираю шорты
Собираю лист
Собираю мэйн
Возвращаю строку

Контроллер:
Вывожу строку

**ИЛИ**

Контроллер:
Собираю данные.

Собираю шорты
Собираю лист
Собираю мэйн

Вывожу строку

**ИЛИ**

Контроллер:
Собираю данные.
Передаю в вьювер

Вьювер:
Собираю шорты
Собираю лист
Собираю мэйн
Вывожу строку

Comment: В целом что-то около того.
_нормально-ли вызывать другие контроллеры из контроллера?_ - не думаю. У нас принято редиректить. Если просто общая логика - выносится на слой повыше (domain, например).

Comment: А если у вас например на главной - тот же контроллер news, но с небольшими изменениями. Например сверху написано "Это главная"?

Проще всего ведь подключить контроллер news, собрать в контроллере main ту самую дополнительную информацию и использовать дальше данные из контроллера news при сборке страницы

Comment: Абсолютно идентичные страницы за исключением заголовка?

Comment: Да. Но это просто пример. Пример в котором я не решил что стоит делать. Мне это не нужно, но это нужно понимать, как и то что на ноль нельзя делить. Для того, что бы знать как принято действовать.

Comment: И не заголовка. А просто частей страницы. Например в начале страницы должно быть h1, а в конце блок с рекламой какой-нибудь

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю как в php принято, но в asp.net mvc принято для каждой страницы свой контроллер, а одинаковые блоки выносят в `partial view`. По идее, такой же аналог должен быть и тут (паттерн-то у всех один)